# Run a custom loop in parallel with the main event loop

Tags: tornado

How can I run an infinite loop

```
# custom infinite loop
while 1:
    print("Hello\n")
```

in parallel with `tornado`'s main event loop ?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Main event loop
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run it in another thread (and deal with the associated synchronization). Or you can make it a coroutine and have it yield to the IOLoop periodically (presumably the real-world version of your code is sleeping instead of just busy-looping; you would use `await tornado.gen.sleep()` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the optimal answer, but running each loop on a thread worked well for me.

```
import threading

application.listen(8888)

event_loop_thread = threading.Thread(target=tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start)
event_loop_thread.daemon = True
event_loop_thread.start()

custom_loop_thread = threading.Thread(target=custom_loop)
custom_loop_thread.daemon = True
custom_loop_thread.start()

while 1:
    pass
```